# Internet dosn't work when connecting hdmi / usb hub

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, mojave

I have bought a brand new MacBook Pro 15' and when I am connecting my screens, the wifi is still connected but the internet doesn't work.
when I am disconnecting the HDMI, the internet comes back.
I read that this is a known problem, but I didn't get any solution...

What should I do?

Comment: normally monitors do not interfere with internet. Show us your WiFi settings

Comment: @Buscar웃, absolutely right, but this is happening also to my brother MacBook pro 15, so this is a problem with all the MacBooks.

Comment: @danielAzuelos, yes. when i am disconnecting the hdmi, the internet is immediatly comes back.

Comment: Please add this key detail in your original question. Comments are just here to improve questions to focus on correct answers.

Comment: @danielAzuelos, the cables are working with my windows computer :(

Comment: @Nir Berko: don’t waste comments space please, this isn’t the place where to put key information. I will remove all my comments within a few minutes if they are wasted.

Comment: Please add to your OQ if one of your HDMI cable is unshielded?

Comment: What WiFi band is used? 2.4 or 5 GHz? As MBPs don‘t have HDMI natively, what solution is used? USB-C adapter? Can you check the WiFi RSSI and Noise level with the cable connected and disconnected (Option-Click on the WiFi menu bar item)?

Answer (score 2):

Try this, go to system preferences then network preferences. Select Thunderbolt Ethernet and "make service inactive" (click sprocket icon at the bottom)

This improved my WiFi connection speed.  My thought being that Thunderbolt is a multipurpose port also used for ethernet and may be taking priority when it is plugged into any device.  If you are using WiFi Thunderbolt ethernet is obviously not needed.